# Timing React.js Application

Tags: javascript, performance, dom, browser, single-page-application

I am working with a 3rd party APM tool which provides a javascript agent to give insight into the visibility of UI rendering times.

Understanding that that React.js doesn't really map well to the browser timings API, can anyone shed any insight into when I would measure the below metrics? I included the available API calls that the vendor provides.

**Metrics to report**

- End User Response Time - virtualPageStart() to virtualPageEnd()
- HTML Download Time - viewChangeStart() to viewChangeEnd()
- HTML Download & DOM Building Time - viewChangeStart() to viewDOMLoaded()
- DOM Building Time - viewChangeEnd() to viewDOMLoaded()
- DOM Ready Time -    viewChangeStart to viewDOMLoaded

**Available API Calls**

- markViewChangeStart()    Sets the view change start time.
- markViewChangeEnd()  Sets the view change end time.
- markViewDOMLoaded()  Sets the view DOM loaded time.
- markXhrRequestsCompleted() Sets the XHR requests completed time.
- markViewResourcesLoaded() Sets the view resources loaded time.
- markVirtualPageStart() Sets the virtual page start time.
- markVirtualPageEnd() Sets the virtual page end time.

THANKS!!!

Answer (score 0):

For most of these items, you are actually not affected by React itself. You can record the changestart/changeend events with your routing library. If you don't use any routing library, your pseudocode would look like this:

```
markViewChangeStart();
ReactROM.render(component, domNode, function() {
    markViewChangeEnd();
});
```

For DOM loaded, you can use the first time markViewChangeEnd is called:

```
markViewChangeStart();
ReactROM.render(component, domNode, function() {
    if (!window.rendered) {
        markViewDOMLoaded();
        window.rendered = true;
    }
    markViewChangeEnd();
});
```

For the RequestsComplete event, you can hold a global variable to mark you have started making requests, an when all of your requests are resolved, call the RequestsCompleted() event.

I think page start and end events can be called at the same place with changeend and change start.

For the ResourcesLoaded, I'm not sure how it could be handled.